# Module could not be found (VSTS Build with Windows 10 SDK for Creators update )

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-iot-core-10, dragonboard

We are creating appxbundle on VSTS for UWP apps. The builds are successful, however at runtime we are getting exception while accessing the following method:

```
public static Task<DeviceManagementClient> CreateAsync(IDeviceTwin deviceTwin, IDeviceManagementRequestHandler hostAppHandler);
```

**Exception:**

```
    The specified module could not be found. 
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD) 
at SystemConfiguratorProxyClient.SCProxyClient..ctor() at Microsoft.Devices.Management.SystemConfiguratorProxy..ctor() 
at Microsoft.Devices.Management.DeviceManagementClient.<CreateAsync>d__7.MoveNext() ---
```

**Build Machine:** 
Windows Server 2012 R2 with Windows 10 SDK Fall creators update

**Runtime:**
Dragonboard with Windows 10 RS3 build

We followed the UWP build template for creating the app packages.

What are we missing?

Comment: What's the result if you generate the package manually on local machine and use this package?

Comment: we don't see the exception, when the package is built on local machine

Comment: Try to generate the package on your build machine manually (MSBuild) and check whether it has the issue. Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: sorry I could not get the details, that you have asked for yet. But we observed that this is happening only with release build, local or VSTS. Debug build we don't see this exception.

Comment: What do you mean debug build? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive if you can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was we had a custom Nuget package which was built in Debug version, hence it was not working in release build configuration. Thanks!